# If 13 does not divide m, then prove that $m^4+8$ is not a cube of an integer

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

My question is how can we prove that $m^4 + 8$  not a cube of an integer if 
 $m$ can not be divided by 13.

What I have done so far:

By Fermat’s Little Theorem:
\begin{align}
m^{p-1} &\equiv 1 \pmod p \\
m^{13-1} &\equiv 1 \pmod{13} \\
m^{12} &\equiv 1 \pmod{13} \\
(m^4)^3 &\equiv 1 \pmod{13}.
\end{align}

I am not sure how to use this information to prove the original question though.

Comment: Do you have a *question*? It appears that you only have a demand right now.

Comment: Hint: what are the possible values of $m^4+8$ and $x^3$ mod $13$?

Comment: @user296602 edited, thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: @RobertIsrael  So for $m^4+8m^4+8$, we have the following $x$: 8, 9, 24, 89? and for $x^3$ mod 13, we would have non-integer answers. How do I prove that with a proof using modular arithmetic though?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you for the suggestion, I have updated with more information

Comment: @SinghChief  I meant, what are the values of $m^4+8 \mod 13$ where $m = 1, 2, \ldots, 12$?  What are the values of $x^3 \mod 13$ where $x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots, 12$?

Comment: I don't understand. The question is: Prove that if $m^4+8$ is a cube, then $13|m$?

Comment: @Mircea Im trying to prove that $m^4 + 8$ is NOT a cube, because m is NOT divisible by 13.

Comment: @SinghChief Do you know about the equivalence between $p\to q$ and $\neg q \to \neg p$?

Comment: Fermat's little theorem is often, but not always, useful. In this particular case, it is much easier to do some arithmetic modulo 13.